# Tweepy API fail to verify company's certification

Tags: python, ssl, twitter, certificate, tweepy

I am encountering issues with SSL and certificate verification for Tweepy. For instagram, I am able to use my company's certificate to send a request and pull the required user data however it seems to not work for Twitter using the Tweepy python library. I have modified part of the API to forcefully add a cert when making a request to Twitter (cert=company.pem) as follows:

```
try:
    resp = self.session.request(self.method,
                                full_url,
                                data=self.post_data,
                                timeout=self.api.timeout,
                                auth=auth,
                                proxies=self.api.proxy,
                                **cert="company.pem"**
                                )
```

However upon execution of the follow set of code:

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.secure = True
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth, proxy='internet.mycompany.com:443')
print(api.me().name)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 539, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 727, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 238, in connect
    ssl_version=resolved_ssl_version)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 279, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\ssl.py", line 246, in wrap_socket
    _context=self)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\ssl.py", line 350, in __init__
    raise x
  File "C:\Python33\lib\ssl.py", line 346, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\ssl.py", line 553, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:548)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 370, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 574, in urlopen
    raise SSLError(e)
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:548)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tweepy\binder.py", line 188, in execute
    proxies=self.api.proxy
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 465, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 431, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:548)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/kteh/PycharmProjects/NewTwitterProject/TwitterTest.py", line 18, in <module>
    print(api.me().name)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tweepy\api.py", line 337, in me
    return self.get_user(screen_name=self.auth.get_username())
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tweepy\auth.py", line 136, in get_username
    user = api.verify_credentials()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tweepy\api.py", line 630, in verify_credentials
    )(**kargs)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tweepy\binder.py", line 241, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tweepy\binder.py", line 191, in execute
    raise TweepError('Failed to send request: %s' % e)
tweepy.error.TweepError: Failed to send request: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:548)
```

I have tried researching for similar problems but I have not found any mention of specifying certificates for Tweepy that has worked. Setting verify=False does not work as well as a bypass. The python code runs properly in my home network but not in my corporate network. I am required to make it run in the corporate network using my company's certificate as I have done with Instagram Python API.

**Edit:** I tried installing the cert and it is now giving me a new error

```
tweepy.error.TweepError: Failed to send request: [SSL] PEM lib
```